# High CPU on MySql Fusion-io server

Tags: mysql, cpu-usage, innodb, mysql5.5, fusionio

I've just finished reading this old Q&A which had some really good detailed information on a similar setup to ours, though unfortunately our problem (now) is not with replication.

[MySQL Replication Performance](https://serverfault.com/questions/408631/mysql-replication-performance/409416)

We have a new master database server (Server version: **5.5.27**-log MySQL Community Server) that is on a bare metal server with the following specs:

- 2 x Intel E5-2620-v2
- 64Gb Memory
- 2 x Fusion-io 600Gb card (Raid 1) for MySql
- 1 x SSD for Centos 6.5
- 1Gbps Network

HyperThreading has not been disabled on the server as there is mixed opinions about whether this helps on large memory systems, but we're not against trying it.

We currently replicate to 3 slaves that are virtualised on a SSD cluster. We were replicating to 4 but this seemed too much for the SSD cluster and we had periods of lag.

All tables are InnoDB and master DB and slave **Writes** are between **3.5K - 2.5K qps**, whilst  **Reads** on the master are about **7.5k - 10k qps**.

The settings for the master DB are as follows:

```
long-query-time=10
slow-query-log

max_connections=500
max_tmp_tables=1024

key_buffer = 1024M
max_allowed_packet = 32M

net_read_timeout=180
net_write_timeout=180

table_cache = 512

thread_cache = 32
thread_concurrency = 4 

query_cache_type = 0 
query_cache_size = 0M 

innodb_file_per_table
innodb_file_format=barracuda

innodb_buffer_pool_size=49152M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=2
innodb_read_io_threads=16
innodb_write_io_threads=16
innodb_io_capacity = 500

innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=20M
innodb_log_file_size=1024M
innodb_log_files_in_group = 2

innodb_doublewrite=0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
```

Our problem is with CPU load, especially Sys Cpu. As you can see from mpstat we have 0% iowait and very high %sys.

```
Linux 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64            13/11/14    _x86_64_    (24 CPU)

13:57:18     CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
13:57:19     all   23.35    0.00   74.65    0.00    0.00    0.88    0.00    0.00    1.13
13:57:20     all   21.95    0.00   75.50    0.00    0.00    0.96    0.00    0.00    1.59
13:57:21     all   23.74    0.00   72.63    0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    2.63
13:57:22     all   23.88    0.00   71.64    0.00    0.00    1.17    0.00    0.00    3.31
13:57:23     all   23.26    0.00   73.89    0.00    0.00    0.92    0.00    0.00    1.92
13:57:24     all   22.87    0.00   74.87    0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    1.25
13:57:25     all   23.41    0.00   74.51    0.00    0.00    0.96    0.00    0.00    1.12
```

Previously the master database was running on a virtualised server (same SSD cluster as the slaves).  It had a host to itself within the vSphere cluster which had:

- 2 x Intel X5570
- 32Gb of memory
- SSD shared from cluster

There was never any problem before, the server ran without fault for many years, albeit with lower SQL throughput.

Queries are all simple and indexes have been optimized for inserts & updates as complex client queries are carried out on the slaves. There are no deletes, only inserts & updates.  Most tables (all big ones) have primary keys.

The CPU usage seems to grow once the memory buffer is full, and MySql is the only application being run on the server.

Connections range from about 200-400 with around 100-200 of those running.  Innodb Buffer Pool Hit Ratio is 100%.  There's no swap memory ever being created so I cannot see this being the issue:

http://blog.jcole.us/2010/09/28/mysql-swap-insanity-and-the-numa-architecture/

We have a ton of history with New Relic but unfortunately I cannot paste in screenshots here.

I've gone through countless blogs and Q&As like this but cannot find any cause nor solution so am putting it out there.. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

It seems I can now post screenshots.  These two captures from New relic show the system load and query load on the server over a 6 hour window with a restart of mysql in the middle.

[image: System Load]

[image: Query load]

Comment: If you want to post screenshots, just post the links and someone with enough rep can edit them in for you.

Comment: Lots of tuning options. Can you share the filesystem in use, the hardware configuration (server make/model) and mountpoint configuration (output of `mount`)?

Comment: I wish you would have posted the information I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB and FusionIO are very CPU-aggressive individually, but even more so together.

I have old posts about this

- `Aug 25, 2013` : [MySQL / Fusion IO Configuration Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48700/877)
- `Jun 19, 2013` : [MySQL using too much CPU](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44906/877)

The key here is to be a little more liberal in tuning InnoDB.

## SUGGESTIONS

You need to choose one or more of the following suggestions:

- Decide which version of MySQL you want to have

  - Upgrade to MySQL 5.6.21 ([*better InnoDB Storage Engine*](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/whats-new-in-mysql-5.6.html#innodb) + [*Latest Security Patch*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/80503/877))
  - Upgrade to MySQl 5.5.40 ([*Latest Security Patch*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/80503/877))
- Bump up [**innodb_buffer_pool_instances**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_instances) to 8 (This is MySQL 5.6 default)
- Max out the IO Threads

  - [**innodb_read_io_threads**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads) = 64
  - [**innodb_write_io_threads**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) = 64
- Increase [**innodb_log_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size) = 128M for Better Log Writing Performance
- Double [**innodb_io_capacity**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_io_capacity) to 1000
- Increase [**innodb_io_capacity_max**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_io_capacity_max) to 2000 (MySQL 5.6 only)
- Increase [**innodb_purge_threads**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_purge_threads) to 4 (MySQL 5.6 only)
- [Compare innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit set to 0 instead of 2 to see which flushes smoother](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74433/why-is-there-no-data-loss-with-mysql-innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit-set-to-0/74438#74438) (Maybe be six of one and half dozen of the other)

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Many thanks for your comments & suggestions.  We applied some code changes to the services writing to the database to batch inserts & updates where possible and since then the server has been running perfectly (3 days straight now).  So until it goes bad again I won't change anything :)

Comment: We previously did have a higher count for innodb_buffer_pool_pages.  We tried 3, 4, 6, 8 pool instances and the higher numbers always performed worse results. 2-3 seems to work best for us.

We also set the innodb_io_capacity to 500 after reading this blog where higher values didn't yield any benefit: http://www.percona.com/blog/2010/12/20/mysql-5-5-8-and-percona-server-being-adaptive/

I think the next step required is to upgrade the DB server to 5.6 and/or Percona.